# Columnas de gráfico tipo Line

Tags: genexus

Teniendo como objetivo lograr el siguiente gráfico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Logré obtener los valores de cada una de las jornadas de manera correcta, pero los mismos se muestran en la misma "columna" cuando el gráfico es de tipo Line:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo es posible mostrar los valores en 3 columnas independientes? Probé cambiando algunas propiedades Format > Type > Datum/Axis sin éxito. Esto sumado a que no tengo ningún atributo para agrupar por rango de horario. Si el gráfico es de tipo Column, me lo muestra en 3 columnas diferentes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

@Chona En un principio la idea era hacer algo de este estilo, una query con 3 valores:

```
Count(TurCod) IF hour(TurFec) >= 0 and hour(TurFec) < 8
Count(TurCod) IF hour(TurFec) >= 8 and hour(TurFec) < 16
Count(TurCod) IF hour(TurFec) >= 16 and hour(TurFec) < 24
```

Ante la imposibilidad e ignorancia de cómo lograrlo, terminé haciendo 3 nuevos atributos, los cuales se ponen en 1 o 0 dependiendo de la condición:

```
- Tur0a8: 1 IF hour(TurFec) >= 0 and hour(TurFec) < 8; 0 OTHERWISE
- Tur8a16: 1 IF hour(TurFec) >= 8 and hour(TurFec) < 16;0 OTHERWISE
- Tur16a24: 1 IF hour(TurFec) >= 16 and hour(TurFec) < 24;0 OTHERWISE
```

y en la Query 3 valores:

```
Sum(TurHor0a8) / Count(TurCod) * 100
Sum(TurHor8a16) / Count(TurCod) * 100
Sum(TurHor16a24) / Count(TurCod) * 100
```

Intenté hacerlo cómo dices, pero me da error de sintaxis, si lo hago de la siguiente forma:

```
"00 a 08 hs" if TurHor0a8 > 0; "16 a 24 hs" if TurHor16a24 > 0; "8 a16" if TurHor8a16 > 0; "Otros" otherwise
```

El gráfico me queda así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

La gráfica que mostras como objetivo a lograr corresponde a un solo indicador (% de turnos WEB) cortado por rango de horario (esta sería la dimensión).

Por lo que comentas, no tenes ningún atributo para agrupar por rango de horario. Parecería que acumulas en tres atributos diferentes (TurHor0a8, TurHor8a16 y TurHor16a24).

Si es así, la solución de mostrarlo en columnas que lograste me parece la mejor solución (no lo mostraría en una gráfica de líneas).

Si aún así quisieras mostrarlo usando una gráfica de líneas habría que transformar la consulta en UN indicador cortado por UNA dimensión.

Sin contar con la estructura de la transacción para ver de qué atributos dispones es medio difícil arriesgar una solucion, pero podria funcionar algun truco como este:

```
"00 a 08 hs" IF TurHor0a8 > 0; 
"08 a 16 hs" IF TurHor8a16 > 0; 
"16 a 24 hs" OTHERWISE Sum(TurHor0a8 + TurHor8a16 + TurHor16a24);
```

La primera expresión es la dimensión y la segunda el indicador.
Solo funciona si no hay dos atributos TurHor0a8, TurHor8a16 y TurHor16a24 que sean distintos de cero para el mismo registro, pero todo dependerá de cómo estés grabando los datos.